# Select items from List<>

Tags: c#

I have this List defined as property :

```
List<string> colors= new List<string>(); 
colors.Add("Red"); 
colors.Add("Blue"); 
colors.Add("Green");
colors.Add("Black");
```

And I have this function:

```
private List<string> getColors(string colorName , List<string> headers)
{
     List<string> list2return = colors(return all colors except red and black);
     return list2return ;
}
```

My question is how can I select from list all items except `red` and `black`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?:

```
colors.Where(c => !c.Equals("Red") && !c.Equals("Black")).ToList()
```

Or, if you need it to be case-insensitive:

```
colors.Where(c =>
    !c.Equals("Red", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
    !c.Equals("Black", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
).ToList()
```

(Though it's not really clear why that method has parameters which aren't being used.  Or how it has access to the `colors` variable in the first place, since that really doesn't look like a class-level member.)

Comment: how does '=>' work? How is this construct being used/called in C# ?

Comment: Look for Lambda Expression

Comment: @Juraj - in this context I read it in my head as `for any colour c` *such that* `c is not black and c is not red`.  Does that help?

Comment: Dave, tnx. But What if I make comparison with this string "red" not "Red" (i.e. i need to make it case not sensitive)

Comment: @Michael: `string.Equals()` has overloads for that.  I've updated the answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is like this:

```
colors.Except(new[] { "Red", "Black" });
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11506933)

Comment: @theMayer [Looks valid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) to me and more self explanatory than `color.Where( /* ... */ );`

Comment: It looks more like a comment. Typically, we like answers to contain a bit more explanation than "here, try this."